# What are the charts routes of failing and passing the bot tests?

Tags: the-talos-principle

I have took the two part tests of the terminal to check that I'm not a bot for creating new account.
I passed the test and I took it again to see if there is any way to fail at it.
Out of curiosity, to see if there is an actual option to fail at this, I choose the most ridiculous answers I though will be forced me to fail, but somehow I passed the test again...
And on the other hand, my friend took those tests and fail on his first time (maybe I should have doubted his humanity).

What I want to know is the possibilities charts of passing/failing the test.

Comment: I don't know myself, but I have two theories: theory one is that it is totally random, however, I don't like this one because it's not scientifically verifiable and also the game is otherwise entirely deterministic. Theory two is that you fail if you don't have any contradictions in your test, this one should be easy to test if you can go back to the save point where you take the test. Both theories are probably wrong, though, I'm just shooting in the dark.